# What is the meaning of Christoffel symbols in the context of manifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I am trying to re-learn differential geometry and I ran into a conceptual wall regarding Christoffel symbols. I think I understand their meaning in the context of a change of coordinates, but I fail to see their meaning wihtin the context of diffrentiable manifolds.

As far as I understand, if we have a change of coordinates, the variation of the basis vectors $v_k$ is itself a vector of the same space whose components are the Christoffel symbols when that vector is expressed in that same basis ( the $v_k$'s).

On the other side, if I have a differentiable manifold, I think I understood that the Christoffel symbols can be seen (in a similar fashion as before) as the components of the variation (i.e. of the derivative) of the basis vectors of the tangent space, expressed in those same basis vectors.

But how are we sure that the derivative of a tangent vector lives/stays on the tangent space? If it does not (and I think in general it does not) how can it be expressed as a combination of the basis vectors of the tangent plane?

To clarify my question: the Christoffel symbols are the component of what vector, in the context of a differentiable manifold?

Comment: The manifolds you're studying are submanifolds of Euclidean space? Otherwise, you cannot make sense of differentiating the basis for the tangent spaces. Of course, this is why we have connections on vector bundles (e.g., tangent bundles) in the general case, and that's what Christoffel symbols are — they're representing the components of the covariant derivatives of the (local) frames of the bundles.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not at your level of conversation. I don't know what a connection is, let alone covariant derivatives or frames..

Comment: I'm telling you what the context of Christoffel symbols is. When you have a submanifold of $\Bbb R^n$, you are in fact calculating the *tangential* components of the derivatives of your basis vectors. You cannot make sense of this unless your submanifold is sitting in Euclidean space.

Comment: I suggest that you look at the explanation of Christoffel symbols and figure out which symbols and words you don't understand. Go back and learn them carefully before trying to understand Christoffel symbols. In particular, you do need to understand all the words used by @TedShifrin in his comments before you can understand what a Christoffel symbol is. For example, there are no Christoffel symbols defined on just a differentiable manifold. They are defined only if there is a connection (covariant derivative) defined on the manifold. You have to learn what that is first.